# Google search using Chrome triggers a call to the website

Tags: google-chrome

I am a little confused by this behaviour, so thought I would ask here: when using Google Chrome, and going explicitly to google.com, a search to some websites (ex: wikipedia.com) triggers a call from the browser to the given website. 
That's not the behaviour I would have expected. 
Anyone can confirm this is a wanted/expected behaviour and what could be the rationale?

Regards

[Screen of my tests, proxy used is Charles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1IrP.png)

Comment: It's maybe becuase of the Sitelinks: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: I don't think so since Edge also shows Sitelinks without querying the website.